# Database is locked while doing big insert

Tags: python, database, sqlite

I am playing with some quite large databases and I am making a program to combine a bunch of the for efficiency. When combining with this python code:

```
select = SQL_EXECUTE("SELECT routes.route_id, route_short_name, route_long_name, route_desc, route_type, route_url, route_text_color, trips.trip_id, arrival_time, departure_time, stops.stop_id, stop_sequence, pickup_type, drop_off_type, stop_code, stop_name, stop_desc, stop_lat, stop_lon, zone_id, stop_url, location_type, service_id, trip_headsign, direction_id, block_id FROM stops JOIN stop_times ON stops.stop_id = stop_times.stop_id JOIN trips ON trips.trip_id = stop_times.trip_id JOIN routes ON trips.route_id = routes.route_id")
    for row in select:
        SQL_EXECUTE("INSERT INTO joined(route_id, route_short_name, route_long_name, route_desc, route_type, route_url, route_text_color, trip_id, arrival_time, departure_time, stop_id, stop_sequence, pickup_type, drop_off_type, stop_id, stop_code, stop_name, stop_desc, stop_lat, stop_lon, zone_id, stop_url, location_type, route_id, service_id, trip_id, trip_headsign, direction_id, block_id) VALUES(:route_id, :route_short_name, :route_long_name, :route_desc, :route_type, :route_url, :route_text_color, :trip_id, :arrival_time, :departure_time, :stop_id, :stop_sequence, :pickup_type, :drop_off_type, :stop_id, :stop_code, :stop_name, :stop_desc, :stop_lat, :stop_lon, :zone_id, :stop_url, :location_type, :route_id, :service_id, :trip_id, :trip_headsign, :direction_id, :block_id)"
        , route_id = row['route_id'], route_short_name = row['route_short_name'], route_long_name = row['route_long_name'], route_desc = row['route_desc'], route_type = row['route_type'], route_url = row['route_url'], route_text_color = row['route_text_color'], trip_id = row['trip_id'], arrival_time = row['arrival_time'], departure_time = row['departure_time'], stop_id = row['stop_id'], stop_sequence = row['stop_sequence'], pickup_type = row['pickup_type'], drop_off_type = row['drop_off_type'], stop_code = row['stop_code'], stop_name = row['stop_name'], stop_desc = row['stop_desc'], stop_lat = row['stop_lat'], stop_lon = row['stop_lon'], zone_id = row['zone_id'], stop_url = row['stop_url'], location_type = row['location_type'], service_id = row['service_id'], trip_headsign = row['trip_headsign'], direction_id = row['direction_id'], block_id = row['block_id'])
```

where SQL_EXECUTE is:

```
# Configure the SQL database
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("sqlite:///"+ dbFile)

# A function to execute SQL
def SQL_EXECUTE(statement, **params):
    con = engine.connect()
    statement = sqlalchemy.text(statement)
    toReturn = con.execute(statement, params)
    return toReturn
```

also here is the create statement (ik its a BIT long but it all of the GTFS standard into 1 table just for testing):

```
CREATE TABLE "joined"(
    "route_id"  TEXT,
    "route_short_name"  INTEGER,
    "route_long_name"   TEXT,
    "route_desc"    TEXT,
    "route_type"    INTEGER,
    "route_url" TEXT,
    "route_color"   TEXT,
    "route_text_color"  TEXT,
    "shape_id"  INTEGER,
    "shape_pt_lat"  REAL,
    "shape_pt_lon"  REAL,
    "shape_pt_sequence" INTEGER,
    "trip_id"   TEXT,
    "arrival_time"  TEXT,
    "departure_time"    TEXT,
    "stop_sequence" INTEGER,
    "pickup_type"   INTEGER,
    "drop_off_type" INTEGER,
    "stop_id"   TEXT,
    "stop_code" INTEGER,
    "stop_name" TEXT,
    "stop_desc" TEXT,
    "stop_lat"  REAL,
    "stop_lon"  REAL,
    "zone_id"   TEXT,
    "stop_url"  TEXT,
    "location_type" INTEGER,
    "service_id"    TEXT,
    "trip_headsign" TEXT,
    "direction_id"  INTEGER,
    "block_id"  INTEGER
)
```

I think that I am getting this error: `sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) database is locked` because what I am trying to INSERT is too big, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is most likely not because the SQL is too large but that there is another database query that has locked the table.
SQLite does not allow more than a single process to access the database at a time so I would check to see if there are any non-committed/hanging queries caused by other areas of the application.